# How to remove locally synced contacts after iOS 7 and Mavericks upgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, macos, contacts

Is there a way to remove contacts from an iPhone running iOS 7 that has locally synced contacts and Calendars (On My Mac) now that the Mac has been updated to Mavericks?

Answer (score 1):

Syncing through Sync Services is not possible anymore for contacts as Sync services was removed from Mavericks.

You'll have to manually delete the contacts/calendars/etc. on your iOS device by going to the bottom of the contact and selecting the red `Delete contact`.